# Can I test the generic type of another generict type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a generic type such as `type A<X, Y, Z> = {}`. Can I make a test function which could detect the concrete types from an input value extends this `type A`?

```
type A<X, Y, Z> = {}

const a : A<number, string, boolean>

function test<T extends A>(toTest:T) {
  // Can I test type X, Y, Z of input value here?
}

test(a)
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types

Comment: Yes you can, but "test" them how? What do you want to do with those once you've tested them? If you can be more specific we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell, but I think you want something like this?

```
type A<X, Y, Z> = {}

declare function test<T extends A<unknown, unknown, unknown>>(toTest: T):
  T extends A<infer X, infer Y, infer Z>
    ? X extends string
      ? true
      : false
    : false

declare const a: A<number, string, boolean>
test(a) // false, X is not a string

declare const b: A<string, string, boolean>
test(b) // true, X is a string
```

Let's break that down.

---

First is the generic constraint:

```
function test<T extends A<unknown, unknown, unknown>>(toTest: T)
```

A types generic parameters *must* have values, but you don't have to commit to what that values are. Here `unknown` just serve as a placeholder that lets you pass in anything.

---

Next is this nested conditional type:

```
  T extends A<infer X, infer Y, infer Z>
    ? X extends string
      ? true
      : false
    : never
```

The return type of this function is where we can pull out those generic parameters.

The first says that if `T` is a subtype of `A<any, any, any>`, then infer the type of each generic parameter in those slots. You can then use those types after the `?` of the conditional type.

If `T` does not extend `A<any, any, any>` then it jumps to the last line and becomes `never`. Though in this case, that can't happen since the constraint is assignable to this type. But this is the required syntax to use `infer SomeType`.

Now we can do a test on one of those types. In this case, we test if it's a `string` with `X extends string`. If it is a string, then the type becomes `true`, else it becomes `false`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAggPADQDRQJooFoD4oF4oDeAvgFAkAmEAxgDYCGATtAGYCuAdlcAJYD27UYBADOwOABUoEAB5D25YbDgcA1u14B3dilXqtO9ms3ssWABTBe4kcABcUcQEpbJKA6myI8xfG7tmEAxQyFB+AUHoof6BUNiublAA-MEecgpQogx+AObxCUmCDKwQeQn2zHQ0wiX59uwQAG6BZJS0jNBU-KJQdPbw7KwAtgBGgSiZOSjDvLw0EHQmJEKiZnSOUAD0G1AVVRAoCKGK6sA9GcBZ7LkU1PRMUJ3s3cN9cBNX4xeTUNOz84vLYBmYbrLaFYoHI5nd65IA)

---

Implementing this function is another matter, I'm purely staying in typeland with this answer.

Comment: What I want was to auto generate another type based on the input value with the same T template. The `infer` gives me the right types. Thanks.